# Whats the effect of the Psychological Profile on gameplay/story?

Tags: mass-effect-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Shepard's background (Origin and Reputation) matter?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/56548/does-shepards-background-origin-and-reputation-matter)

During character creation, you're given several choices for your character "background" (origin, reputation and combat loss). What are the effects of your choices on gameplay? Do this affect story and conversations only or character skills as well? Is there a "good choice"?

Comment: I actually searched a bit to see if this has been asked and didn't find your question for some reason.

Comment: Probably since I didn't mention that they're part of the "psychological profile".  It's good to have dupes that use different words :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will affect some of the dialogs in Mass Effect 3, but you won't have any side quest mission based on your background (contrary to the first Mass Effect).

> for instance if you are a spacer, which means your mum is alive, and you talk to her in the previous one, You will worry about her a different point in the game, and learn from Hackett, that she is in a 'safely' keeping the Crucible.
> Other exemple if Shepard was Sole Survivor background, there might be some references to Akuze and  the thresher maw, mainly on the Tuchunka main mission.

Comment: In my playthrough, it was Hackett, and he said "She's guarding the crucible. I figured another Shepard couldn't hurt".

Comment: In fact you are totaly right Rare Candy, I've done this by memory, but my memory wasn't that perfect. To repair this, might be time to begin another play through".

Comment: Did you mean "not any side quest"?

Comment: @Ben Brocka, yep that was what I meant, but there is still progress to achieve with my english. (I corrected the sentence to make it more clear)